# How do I run the setState function from another screen in react native navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating an app that has 3 main pages using react-native navigation:

Homescreen,
Historikk,
and Kjøring

The screen named Homescreen is the Bottom stack and the others are stacked ontop.

In my page called "Kjøring" I have a button that functions as a start and stop button, using a conditional to decide what is displayed for the user, and what onClick function should be used.

```js
<View>
                {!start?
                    //START KNAPP
                    <View style={styles.startContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleStart} style={styles.startButton}>
                            <Image style={styles.playImage} source={require("../Images/Play.png")} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.startContainerText}>Start</Text>
                    </View>
                :
                    //STOPP KNAPP
                    <View style={styles.startContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleStop} style={styles.startButton}>
                            <Image style={styles.playImage} source={require("../Images/Stop.png")} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.startContainerText}>Stopp</Text>
                    </View>
                }

</View>
```

My problem is that when i press the start button and navigate back to the bottom stack ( Homescreen ), and then back to the page: "Kjøring".
The button is displaying the Start button, instead of the Stop button because my state has been reset.

I then tried to create the state in the Homescreen and send the state to the "Kjøring" screen, and I could send the current state from the Homescreen to the "Kjøring" screen using:

```js
const [started, setStarted] = useState(true);

onPress={() => {navigation.navigate("Kjøring",{started: started})}}
```

I could have tried sending the current state the same way, but i am using the default header and back button of react-native stack navigation v6, so i have no way to send it with when i go back without recreating the header.

**I cannot find out how to send the setState function to the "Kjøring" screen.**

I have tried:

- Creating a function and sending it as a prop like i did with the started state
- Passing the setState itself through as a prop
- Passing an arrow function that sets changes it

Comment: It's better to use a state manager(react-redux) for your use case.

Comment: have you tried DeviceEventEmitter.addListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think DeviceEventEmitter should work in your case

in Home Page add a listener

```
 useEffect(() => {
      DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('event.testEvent', eventData => {//action that need to be performed});
    return () => {};   }, []);
```

In the Page where the event happens emit the following code:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.emit('event.testEvent', true);
```

Also remove the listener on exiting the Page by adding the below code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  
    return () => {
      DeviceEventEmitter.removeAllListeners('event.testEvent');
    };
   
  }, []);
```